# CentOS: determine IP for network device

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, centos, ethernet

When CentOS boots up, it tries to determine the IP for a network device (eth0) and fails.

```
'Determining IP information for eth0... failed; no link present.'
```

I'm curious to know how, after booting up, I could set the IP information for a wireless device, wlan0, manually.

Another way of putting this questions is: **if CentOS is able to determine IP information for a network device on bootup, what settings is it configuring exactly?**

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to get an IP address (and gateway, etc.) from the DHCP server to get your computer into the network.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CentOS Team's well documented [**Wireless How-To**](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless) guide. What your OS is currently doing is using `dhclient` to probe your devices and search for a DHCP server to obtain a lease.